# Reading a Python File for Matching Parentheses and getting Parentheses Pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some Python Code which uses a Stack method to find and check for matching parentheses, howeverm I also needs to find the amount of pairs of these parentheses.

```
def parChecker(symbolString):
    s = Stack()
    balanced = True
    index = 0
    while index < len(symbolString) and balanced:
        symbol = symbolString[index]
        if symbol in "([{":
            s.push(symbol)
        else:
            if s.isEmpty():
                balanced = False
            else:
                top = s.pop()
            if not matches(top,symbol):
                balanced = False
        index = index + 1
    if balanced and s.isEmpty():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def matches(open,close):
    opens = "([{"
    closers = ")]}"
    return opens.index(open) == closers.index(close)
```

My questions are, how would I implement the opening of the python files to check for matching and how would I go about printing the amount of matched pairs, as well as which specific pairs matched and which did not? Also, s=Stack() is me using another class Stack that I created.

Comment: Are you checking for matching brackets in Python source code files? If so, have you considered how you want to handle brackets contained inside string literals?

Comment: @TomDalton  Well, I am only checking for (,{,[.

Comment: Assuming that you *are* trying to do this with python source code, consider a file with contents like `do_thing("(")`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @TomDalton    I want to output that it has one matching pair of () and that not all ( match.

Comment: OK that makes it easier. Can you just count the number of each character? Then if you have 10 `(` and 11 `)` then you know you have 10 matching pairs of `()` and one mismatched `)`? Then the next question is if you have a file with `([)]` in it, is that counted as 2 matching pairs or all mismatched? From your code above I think it's intended to be the second option?

Comment: @TomDalton    2 matching pairs still.

Comment: In that case I think a simple counting algorithm is fine, just count how many of each opening and closing bracket you have, and see if the totals match or not.

Comment: @TomDalton Would you care to show how would I do that in my parChecker function?